# Positioning Y-Axis in Composed charts- Recharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I have created a composing chart using recharts as attached here :

[image]

this issue is if I add a label on Y-axis that contains more than 8 letters it either goes to the next line or out of the container, I wrote a workaround where I just show the acronyms on the Y-axis and then the description in the tooltip but the requirement is to show the complete name in the label on Y-axis, so is there any way we can move the Y-axis on the right-hand side so that we can allot more space to the label?

I tried adding a domain to X-axis  which did not help much